# Interrupts stop executing after vector, SEI and intflags are still set. (AtMega4809)

Tags: c, embedded, interrupt, avr, atmega

I have several interrupts in the system, including TC capture, external interrupts and ADC conversion interrupts. There's one vector in particular that, when executed, will prevent ANY vector from executing even after the `reti()` instruction.

The TCB2 Capture interrupt vector (Vector 25) is the only vector in the system that stops everything leading to a WDT reset.

Global Interrupt Flag is 1, and the INTFLAGS for the activated interrupts get set correctly when an interrupt occurs. But no vector is executed.
This applies for all interrupts.

I've tried changing the vector a little, making sure the `reti()` instruction is present and making sure the vector table didn't change.
I also already made sure the code kept executing normally after the `reti()`. The only thing that seems not to work are vectors.

```
volatile uint8_t new_input_regs = 0x00;

/*[Other code, including other vectors without this issue]*/

void __vector_25() {

    new_input_regs = PORTD_IN;  //Get PORTD input values
    TCB2_CTRLA &= ~(0x01); //Clear TC enable and flags
    TCB2_INTFLAGS = 0xFF;

    asm("WDR"); //Reset the WD timer

    event_type = EVENT_INPUT_INTERRUPT; //Set the event
    reti();     
}
```

After this executes, all interrupts stop working until reset (This also causes a Watchdog Reset eventually due to no interrupts executing).

More info about the register and vector table here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f27lR.jpg

Comment: Kicking the wdog from inside a ISR is a cardinal sin, don't do that.

Comment: Anyway, why do you call `reti` manually when you don't store the SREG manually? The compiler, upon realizing that this is an ISR, should do all of that for you. Remove it and disassemble the code, see what you get.

Comment: The code originally didn't have the reti() instruction in any ISR. For some reason tho, the compiler did not put any reti instructions at the end of the interrupt vectors, so i had to add it manually to the end of all vectors.

Comment: Then something is wrong with the compiler. There should be some way to mark the ISR as an interrupt, such as a non-standard keyword. Otherwise the compiler may go haywire with optimizations etc.

Comment: I'm also moving the WDRs to normal code and will remember not to do WDRs in ISRs in the future. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Lundin can you please explain why you don´t use `wdr` inside of an ISR (only a `C` ISR or a `asm` interrupt too?)? It´s quite new for me.

Comment: @Kampi Because it defeats the very purpose of having a watchdog. If your program gets stuck somewhere but there's a background ISR called repeatedly, you will keep refreshing the watchdog from the ISR even though the main program is stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the comment, i've noticed the ISRs were too optimized, even skipping retis and merging vectors in one single block of assemble with no returns. The default vector functions (Like `__vector_25()` used above) do not work as expected, leading to un-terminated ISRs and missing `reti()` even when manually written. This lead to completely unexpected behaviour.

I've changed the vector definition to `ISR(_VECTOR(25))` and removed `reti()` at the end of functions. Interrupts have resumed working as they should.

Thanks for the help.